# how can i add webpack loader to handle scss-loader @import scss file

Tags: javascript, webpack, sass, sass-loader

my webpack.config.js file is:

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader',
          // custom webpack loader
          'theme-loader',
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

a simple scss file is that:

```
@import "./scss/variable.scss";

.a{
  background: white;
}
```

how can i make `./scss/variable.scss` file to be also processed by `theme-loader`, which is a custom webpack loader in order to handle some sass conversion

Comment: what is `theme-loader` ? and what version of webpack you working on ?

Comment: `theme-loader` is a custom webpack loader to handle some sass conversion

Comment: can you send it's doc website or GitHub ? also can you tell me what is you webpack version ?